# How can I print a Pyramid

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops, cs50, test-pyramid

I'm trying to make a pyramid equal to the input I get from the user but its not working the way. In the output, the 1st line is blank and from the second line it print a Hash and on second 2 and then 3 and so on...
But I want it to start from the 1st line.

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Prompt for height
    int n, i, j;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("height: ");
    }
    while (n < 1 || n > 8);
    // For each row
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 0 < 5
    {
        // For each column
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) 
        {
        printf("#");
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

If I give it `5` as input, I was expexting this Output

```
#
##
###
####
#####
```

But instead, it's giving me this...

```
#
##
###
####
```

what's the problem?

Comment: Not sure how many times this was asked, but if I had to bet, I'd say probably around one million.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a typo

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 0 < 5
                        ^^^^^^
```

If to remove this typo

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    // For each column
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) 
    {
    printf("#");
    }
printf("\n");
}
```

then the inner loop gets the control for i in the range `[0, n-1)`.

So for example in the first execution of the inner loop there is no its iterations because `j = 0` is not less than `i = 0`.

You need to write it like

```
    for (j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
```

Comment: Why use `j < i + 1` and not use `j <= i`?

Comment: @user1234 Is it very important?

Comment: OP seems to be a new comer to C. It would be better to give the idea of what all could be used (just gives a bit more help).